# Magento doesn't change languages

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm trying to configure my Magento store to display content in Spanish, but it isn't working.

I've done the following steps:

1. Download the package from Magento and copying the "es_CO" folder in app > locale
2. Went to Manage Stores and created a new Store View with code "default_spanish"
3. Went to Configuration, selected the new store, unchecked the "Use Website" in Locale Options > Locale and choose Español(Colombia).
4. Flushed the Cache and went to the frontend. The dropdown menu appeared where I'm asked for the language, but when I change stores the language doesn't appears.

I've tried with other language packages and changing the default language, but it isn't working (I'm still getting everything in English). I haven't installed a theme yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reindex data also. Config->Index management->Select all->Reindex data.
Try to run Compilation in Config->System->Tools->Compilation->Run Compilation Process.
Also you can try to delete all folders through ftp into root/var/cache. Let me know if it works.Best Regards.